# Im trying to make macro/hotkey

Tags: python, macros, hotkeys

It just doesnt work i get an error saying

```
AttributeError: 'Controller' object has no attribute 'is_pressed'
```

Code:

```
from pynput.mouse import Button, Controller
from pynput.keyboard import Key, Controller
from pynput.keyboard import Controller
from pynput import mouse
from pynput import keyboard

keyboard = Controller()

while True:
    if keyboard.is_pressed('u'):
        keyboard.press('w')
        keyboard.release('w')
```

Can someone help me out!

Comment: `pynput` has special class `Listener` to catch pressed keys - and it doesn't need `while True`. `Controller` is only to send new keys. Why do you thing that there has to be `is_pressed` ? Did you check [documentation](https://pythonhosted.org/pynput/keyboard.html) ?

Comment: Why did you think that the `is_pressed` attribute should exist?

Answer (score 2):

`pynput` has special class `Listener` to catch pressed keys. It runs in thread and it doesn' need `while True` so it doesn't block main code.

Press `ESC` to stop it.

```
from pynput.keyboard import Key, Controller, Listener

def on_press(key):
    print('{} pressed'.format(key))
    #print(dir(key))

    try:
        if key.char == 'u':
            keyboard.press('w')
            keyboard.release('w')
    except Exception as ex:
        print(ex)
    
def on_release(key):
    print('{} release'.format(key))

    if key == Key.esc:
        # Stop listener
        return False

# --- main ---

keyboard = Controller()

listener = Listener(on_press=on_press, on_release=on_release)

listener.start()

# ... other code ...

listener.join()
```

---

**BTW:**

If you want global macros/hotkeys in system and use Linux then you could use special program [AutoKey](https://github.com/autokey/autokey) for this. It is created with Python and it is has GUI to create macros/script/etc.

If you want global macros/hotkeys in system and use Windows you could rather use popular [AutoHotKey](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/AutoHotkey)

If you want to create macros/hotkeys in some `GUI` programs then you should use `GUI` functions for this.

Answer (score 0):

View [the documentation](https://pynput.readthedocs.io/en/latest/keyboard.html), here's a snippet from it below.

> #### Global hotkeys
>
> A common use case for keyboard monitors is reacting to global hotkeys.
> Since a listener does not maintain any state, hotkeys involving
> multiple keys must store this state somewhere.
>
> *pynput* provides the class `pynput.keyboard.HotKey` for this purpose. It contains two methods to update the state, designed to be easily
> interoperable with a keyboard listener: `pynput.keyboard.HotKey.press`
> and `pynput.keyboard.HotKey.release` which can be directly passed as
> listener callbacks.
>
> [...]
>
> This will create a hotkey, and then use a listener to update its
> state. Once all the specified keys are pressed simultaneously,
> `on_activate` will be invoked.
>
> Note that keys are passed through `pynput.keyboard.Listener.canonical`
> before being passed to the `HotKey` instance. This is to remove any
> modifier state from the key events, and to normalise modifiers with
> more than one physical button.
>
> The method `pynput.keyboard.HotKey.parse` is a convenience function to
> transform shortcut strings to key collections. Please see its
> documentation for more information.
>
> To register a number of global hotkeys, use the convenience class
> `pynput.keyboard.GlobalHotKeys`:

Answer (score 0):

I made an extremely simple opionated library just for this: [envoke](https://pypi.org/project/envoke)

Here's quick example:

```py
from envoke import envoke

# Create a macro sequence
c = envoke()
c.a(interval=0.5).b(interval=0.5).key('5', interval=0.1)

# Run the macro
c.run(start_delay=3.5)
```